# Why is $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }\left ( \frac{1}{2} \right )^{n}= 2$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, geometric-progressions

I'm sorry if this is duplicated, but I can not find any answer to it.

Comment: See
[Sum of Geometric series][1] here; put $q=\frac12$, and you'll obtain want you want.


  [1]: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1306353/why-sum-k-0-infty-qk-sum-is-frac11-q-when-q-1/1306363#1306363

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the geometric series for $|x|<1$
$$1+x+x^2+x^3+....=\frac{1}{1-x}$$
use $x=0.5$
$$1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2^2}+\frac{1}{2^3}+...=\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{2}}=2$$

Answer (score 3):

Here is a nice proof without words:

[image]

Obviously, this doesn't replace an airtight proof, but it is great for intuition.

Answer (score 1):

An explanation for the geometric series:
$(1-x)(1+x+x^2+...+x^n) = 1-x + x-x^2 +x^2 - x^3 + ... + x^n - x^{n+1} = 1-x^{n+1}$ for $n \to \infty$ and $x=\frac 1 2$ you get your series, since $(\frac 1 2)^n \to 0$.